# Countdown problem in Kickstart Round C 2020

Tags: python, algorithm

I tried the Google Kickstart Round C Countdown problem mentioned [here](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ff43/00000000003380d2) with the following approach:

- Converting the input array into a space-separated string
- Deriving the sequence `m m-1 m-2 …1` as another space-separated string.
- Simply count the instances of the 2nd string in the 1st, and since the sequence should be non-overlapping anyway, this approach should work.

However, I'm getting a `WA (Wrong Answer), test set skipped` in practice.

Here’s my code in `python-3`.

```py
t = int(input())

for i in range(t):
    case_num = i + 1
    n, k = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
    # The blank spaces around the input str a and substr_k should deal with cases like [3,2,13]
    a = " " + " ".join([str(int(x)) for x in input().split(" ")]) + " "
    substr_k = " " + " ".join(str(i) for i in reversed(range(1, k+1))) + " "
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(case_num, a.count(substr_k)))
```

Please note that I understand that the approach mentioned in analysis is clearly a better one and I've understood it, however, I’m still trying to figure out as to where I went wrong with the above lazily written code. Since I don’t have access to the actual cases used by `Google` for grading this code, can you someone kindly help me with this? Just a simple case which returns a bad output is fine to know where I went wrong.

**EDIT**: Taking @liju's suggestion into account, I've changed line 6 in my code to better accomodate the case of numbers prefixed with 0's

Comment: This approach will fail when numbers prefixed with zeros like `02,03` instead of `2,3` in test cases.

Comment: @Liju I tried changing line 6 in my code to `a = " " + " ".join([str(int(x)) for x in input().split(" ")]) + " "` as you pointed out. Unfortunately, the result stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an **example**:

String = "abcbabcba"

> String.count("abcba")

This will return 1.

But the number of "abcba" is 2.

Same problem with your code:

**Input:**

1

6 3

3 2 1 3 2 1

**Output:**

1

**Expected Output:**

2

**Explanation:**

Code is finding counts for " 3 2 1 " which have a return value 1 using count function.

Comment: Your suggestion is absolutely on point mate. I thought I had accounted for non-overlapping scenario, but missed the point that I had created this problem for myself when I decided to go with the above approach of using spaces (or any separator, really). Anyway, replacing string.count with a function to check overlapping counts did the trick for me. And it only took me 11 tries in all ;)

Comment: @mkathuri It happens... I think these points could be learnt only by making mistakes.